# How to install dhtmlx

Tags: reactjs, gantt-chart, spfx, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

How to install dhtmlx gantt

```
"dhtmlx-gantt": "^5.1.0"
```

I am developing a webpart in spfx.
`require('dhtmlx');` I am using this line.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Sharepoint demo on GitHub:

https://github.com/kmosti/spfx-gantt

There, Gantt is imported the following way:

```
require("gantt");
```

https://github.com/kmosti/spfx-gantt/blob/master/src/webparts/ganttChart/components/GanttChart.tsx#L28

I am not familiar with Sharepoint, so, I cannot suggest if you need to do something else.

The official documentation describes various ways of how to successfully connect DHTMLX Gantt:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__initializing_gantt_chart.html

For React, you usually need to import Gantt this way:

```
import { gantt } from 'dhtmlx-gantt';
```